# Is it possible to install Windows 8.1 x64 on iMac (Late 2009, 21.5") by using Boot camp?

Tags: windows-8.1, boot-camp

Is it possible to install Windows 8.1 x64 on iMac (Late 2009, 21.5") by using Boot camp? As I know, there's no official support for Boot camp that is able to run Win 8.1 on my Late 2009 iMac. Since I'm going to use GPU-intensive applications (video rendering), I guess VMWare Fusion isn't the best option so I'm looking for any way to install Windows 8.1 on my iMac by using Boot camp.

Comment: have you actually tried it? if not, try it and let us know. ;p

Answer (score 0):

That machine can only run Bootcamp 4, not 5 & is not qualified for Windows 8.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I managed to get Parallels to install Win 8 on my equivalent machine, but I've never tried Bootcamping it to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

How Do You Do It?:

When your IMAC asks you to insert a Windows 7 installation Disc put in a windows 7 disc but when it goes to boot off the disc force shut down your IMAC boot to MAC OS eject the DVD and put in your own Windows 8.1 DVD shut down the IMAC then turn it on while holding Option/Alt and give it a minute and it should come up with windows and Macintosh HD click on windows then press the arrow and there you go.

( I typed this on 2009 IMACc 21.5" running windows 10 )